# Prove that the product of a family of topological vector space is Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, products, topological-vector-spaces

I want to prove that: let $\Lambda \neq \varnothing$ and $E_{\alpha}$ topological vector space, for all $\alpha \in \Lambda$. Then
$$E:=\prod_{\alpha \in \Lambda} E_{\alpha}$$
is a Hausdorff space if, and only if, $E_{\alpha}$ is Hausdorff space, for all $\alpha \in \Lambda$.

I know, by definition

$$E=\left\{f:\Lambda \rightarrow \bigsqcup_{\alpha \in \Lambda }E_{\alpha}\ ; \ f(\alpha)\in E_{\alpha}\right\}.$$

But I don't know how to use this $E$ characterization to prove what I want.

Comment: How does your topology on $E_\alpha$ look?

Comment: And what is the basis of the topology on $E$ are you talking about standard [product topology](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProductTopology.html)?

Comment: If $E_{\alpha}$ is a vector topological vector space, then the topology consider above is a tologogy such that is compatible with the linear structure of$E_{\alpha}$.

Comment: The product topology is the topology whose base is formed by the finite intersections of the inverse images, by the canonical projections, of the open spaces of each topological space that forms the product.

Comment: @Noobmathematician why did you replace $\cup$ for $\sqcup$?

Comment: It is the disjoint union

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108761/discussion-between-guilherme-de-loreno-and-noob-mathematician).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $E$ is hausdorff. Observe that if $E$ is hausdorff then each of its subspaces are hausdorff. If $x,y\in E_\alpha$ and $x\ne y$ then $\exists f,g \in E$ such that $f(\alpha)=x$ , $g(\alpha)=y$ and $f(\beta)=g(\beta)$ for $\alpha\ne \beta\in \Lambda$ then observe that the space $$E_\alpha\times\left(\prod_{\alpha \ne\beta\in\Lambda}f(\beta)\right)\cong E_\alpha$$
So $E_\alpha$ is hausdorff.

Now the converse, if $f,g\in E$ and $f\ne g$, then for some $\alpha\in\Lambda$ such that $f(\alpha)\ne g(\alpha)$. $E_\alpha$ is Hausdorff, so there are disjoint open sets $V$ and $W$ in $E_\alpha$ such that $f(\alpha)\in V$ and $g(\alpha)\in W$. Now we shall take $V$, $W$, and use the definition of product topology on $E$ to find disjoint open sets in $E$, one containing $f$ and the other containing $g$. Now $\pi_\alpha:E\to E_\alpha$ be the canonical projection map. Then we have both $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(V)$ and $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(W)$ open in $E$ . Also $$f\in \pi_\alpha^{-1}(V) \text{ and } g\in \pi_\alpha^{-1}(W)$$ and also $V\cap W=\varnothing\implies \pi_\alpha^{-1}(V)\cap \pi_\alpha^{-1}(W)=\varnothing$. Hence we are done.

Comment: Why $\displaystyle E_\alpha \times \left(\prod_{\alpha\neq \beta \in \Lambda} f(\beta) \right) \cong E_\alpha$?

Comment: And why I can conclude that $E_\alpha$ is Hausdorff? Its because $\displaystyle \left(\prod_{\alpha\neq \beta \in A} f(\beta) \right) \in E$ and $E$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: Are you familiar with subspace topology ?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~idarcy/COURSES/132/HW/homework5.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj0uNHMzePpAhXLxzgGHfJ4DgYQFjABegQIChAG&usg=AOvVaw0WkEcjAssNNOIpWa0x644R&cshid=1591117367911)

Comment: Also observe that $\pi_\alpha$ restriscted to the set $ E_\alpha\times\left(\prod_{\alpha \ne\beta\in\Lambda}f(\beta)\right) $ is a homeomorphism . Try to work this out

Comment: If you still have problem let me know

Comment: I think now everything is clear. Understand. Thank you!

Comment: I sent you a msg in the chat . Have you seen it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108799/discussion-between-guilherme-de-loreno-and-noob-mathematician).

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $f,g\in E$ and $f\ne g$, there is some $\alpha\in\Lambda$ such that $f(\alpha)\ne g(\alpha)$. $E_\alpha$ is Hausdorff, so there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ in $E_\alpha$ such that $f(\alpha)\in U$ and $g(\alpha)\in V$. Now use $U$, $V$, and the definition of the product topology on $E$ to find disjoint open sets in $E$, one containing $f$ and the other containing $g$. I’ve left a further hint in the spoiler protected block below; mouse over to see it.

> Use the projection map $\pi_\alpha:E\to E_\alpha$.